# Smart pointers cast c++17 apple clang

Tags: c++, c++17, clang, smart-pointers

I'm trying to use arrays in smart pointers, but when I cast smart_ptr to weak_ptr using Apple clang I get an error (I use -std=c++17).

```
error: cannot initialize a member subobject of type 'std::weak_ptr<int []>::element_type *' (aka 'int (*)[]') with an lvalue of type 'std::shared_ptr<int []>::element_type *const' (aka 'int *const')
    : __ptr_(__r.__ptr_),
```

Here is an example of code I'm trying to compile.

```
std::shared_ptr<int[]> ptr(new int[5]);
ptr[0] = 1;
ptr[1] = 2;
ptr[2] = 3;

std::weak_ptr<int[]> weakPtr(ptr);

std::cout << ptr[0] << std::endl;
```

P.S. I can't use std::array as I'm implementing my own container class.

Comment: I tested your code in clang 12 and it works. maybe your compiler is old?

Comment: The code snippet provided does not produce the error described.

Comment: What's your apple clang version?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep it is 13.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, where `weak_ptr<T>::element_type` should be defined as `remove_extend_t<T>`, but it is currently defined as `T`. On the other side, `share_ptr<T>::element_type` is correctly defined as `remove_extend_t<T>`.

This inconsistent caused the underlying type of `shared_ptr<T[]>` is `T*`, where the underlying type of `weak_ptr<T[]>` is `T(*)[]`, thus you cannot assign the `shared_ptr<T[]>` to `weak_ptr<T[]>` as expected.

The bug was fixed in this commit: [LWG3001](https://github.com/apple/llvm-project/commit/065ac30026d506172994310bd5badd65120f7d74) and should be included in a future release.

---

A work around is to probably use `shared_ptr<std::array<int, 5>>` and deduce the type for `std::weak_ptr` with `weak_ptr weakPtr(ptr)`.

Note you will not be able to use `shared_ptr::operator []` directly anymore. Instead, you would need to do get the element with `(*ptr)[N]`.